# Resaving posts to update static blocks

Tags: block-editor, save-post

I changed markup in my custom static block and now I have to resave custom posts where I use them in order to update what is shown in the front. I tried to automatise procedure by using wp cli command `wp post update`, but with no success (post is resaved, but only certain field I specify is updated). Is there any way to automatise this?